# how to install python modules sys, os and getopt on unbuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-module

My python version is Python 2.7.17

I usually use pip to install other modules like shutil and itertool etc. I can't find the package name for os, getopt and sys modules.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: They are part of the standard library and don't have to be installed separately.

Comment: One additional note: Python 2 is outdated and if you learn it make sure to start with Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.7 is obsolete and no longer supported (as of 1 January 2020). You should consider using the latest version (currently Python 3.8.5). For more information, see [this](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

The modules you are looking for are core modules of standard Python distribution, therefore they are installed when installing Python itself.

Answer (score 0):

They are installed with your python as part of the standard library, if they are missing, something is wrong with your Python installation and you should reinstall it